# Не верно работает анимация

Tags: ios, objective-c

Такая проблема, есть таблица из n-го числа строк. Таблица перевернута `_tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);` Так, что строка с индексом ноль находится внизу экрана. По верх таблицы добавлено view, изначально позиция равна нулевой строке. Нужно сделать метод, по сути напоминающий лифт. При нажатии на нужную строчку данное view перемещается с помощью анимации на позицию выбранной строки. У меня есть следующий метод:

```
- (void)moveToFloor:(NSInteger)floor
{
    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.layer.position]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.layer.position.x, self.layer.frame.size.height*floor)]];
    [animation setDuration:2.0f];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Но view перемещается не верно. `floor` - номер нажатой строки.

**Обновление**

Вроде трансформ не имеет значения, я сначала подумал, что возможно и координаты таблицы будут перевернуты. Проблема в добавлении view на экран. Не могу получить координаты нужной строки, добавляю view в методе viewDidLoad, но в этот момент ячейки еще не созданы, и я не могу получить координаты. Далее мне надо передать в метод номер строки и вью должен переместиться на данную строчку.

Comment: а то, что оно все перевернуто имеет какое то влияние на код? вроде бы в этой ситуации, трансформ никак не должен влиять? другими словами будет ли оно работать правильно если убрать трансформ? и если можно, опишите, как именно анимируется этит самый лифт

Comment: предполагаю, что view сначала появляется на верхней строке (origin.y=0) а когда случается нажатие на ячейку все объекты уже отрисованны. Как я уже писал, можете описать что именно происходит после нажатия на ячейку? например нажимаю я на третью, куда перемещается view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых, что бы определить номер ячейки, которая была выбрана, Вам нужно использовать метод делегата таблицы `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. В этом методе, вы получите номер, выбранной вами ячейки, затем можно использовать один из данных методов(смотря какой вам нужен)

```
CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect: rectOfCellInTableView toView: [tableView superview]];
```

Здесь вы получите уже координаты выбранной ячейки, в зависимости от того, относительно чего, они вам будут нужны.
Далее, я бы советовал все таки использовать методы попроще, для анимированного передвижения этой view, например, 
`[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`. Здесь вы можете использовать разнообразные маски для анимированного движения, и так же комбинировать их, то есть комбинирую эти маски, можно заставить view двигаться именно так, как Вам нужно.

Comment: @VitaliEller еще такой вопрос, это у вас задача именно такая что бы была перевёрнута таблица?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы индексы строк начинались снизу экрана. Поискал в интернете как это сделать, и умнее чем перевернуть таблицу не нашел.

Comment: @VitaliEller я так и подумал, сам недавно с этим разбирался. Можно сделать проще, лучше, и правильнее, с точки зрения кода. В общем нужно использовать метод     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.objects.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]; Где self.objects это Ваш массив, по которому вы создаёте таблицу.

Comment: не сработало, строка с индексом 0 на верху. Предварительно вернул таблицу в исходное положение.

Comment: Значит все же я Вас не так понял, метод который я писал выше в комментарии скролит таблицу к определённой ячейки, в данном случае до последней, а Вам, именно нужно просто поменять индексы у ячеек.

Comment: Когда таблицы появляется на экране по умолчанию строка с индексом 0 находится на верху экрана, а мне нужно, чтобы она была внизу, а последняя строка на верху.

Comment: Вы заполняете таблицу из какого то массива, так почему бы,?этот массив просто сформировать так как Вам нужно, пусть 0 элемент станет i, а i элемент станет 0, 1 элемент-элементом i-1, и т.д.? Тогда у Вас будет обыкновенная таблица, с индексацией ячеек как и у всех таблиц от меньшего к большему, где 0 ячейка-верхняя ячейка.

Comment: При нажатии на ячейку должен получать номер строки, равный индексу, а если просто заполнить таблицу перевернутым массивом, индексы будут считаться не правильно.

Comment: @VitaliEller То есть Вы просто хотите по нажатию на 0 ячейку получать что это индекс self.array.count? Так вызывайте в методе didSelectRowAtIndex [self moveToFloor:self.objects.count - indexPath.row-1]; Тогда Вы в свой метод будете передавать тот индекс который Вам нужен.